# Laravel: Dropdown from database

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel with infyomlab generator. I want to add data as dropdown from another table.
Here is my code

ProductController.php

```
$supplier = Supplier::all();
$unit = Unit::all();
$category = Category::all();

$products = $this->productRepository->all();
$product = DB::table('products')->select(
    'suppliers.*',
    'units.*',
    'categories.*')
    ->join('suppliers','suppliers.id', '=', 'products.supplier_id')
    ->join('units','units.id', '=', 'products.unit_id')
    ->join('categories','categories.id', '=', 'products.category_id')
    ->get();

return view('products.index', compact('supplier', 'unit', 'category', 'product'))
    ->with('products', $products);
```

fields.blade.php

```
<select class="form-control" name="supplier_id" id="supplier_id">
<option value="">Select Supplier</option>
@foreach($suppliers as $supplier)
    <option value="{{ $supplier->id }}">{{ $supplier->$supplier_name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

but when i press add new product it does not show the form for input it shows the following error

```
Undefined variable: suppliers (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\qa\resources\views\products\fields.blade.php)
```

Comment: You didn't return suppliers from your controller

Comment: please specify briefly.

Answer (score 0):

try This

```
@foreach($products as $supplier)
    <option value="{{ $supplier->id }}">{{ $supplier->$supplier_name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

As u returning it

Comment: bro, it shows the same error "Undefined variable: products (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\qa\resources\views\products\fields.blade.php) "

Answer (score 0):

It's just a typo:

Here, you are returning `supplier` not suppliers `compact('supplier', 'unit', 'category', 'product')`

So you need to perform in front end like:

```
@foreach($supplier as $s)
   <option value="{{ $s->id }}">{{ $s->$supplier_name }}</option>
@endforech
```

Answer (score 0):

You replace it by

```
$supplier = Supplier::all();
```

to

```
$suppliers = Supplier::all();


return view('products.index', compact('suppliers', 'unit', 'category', 'product','products'));
```

Comment: Not works for me can you please give me a fresh code to show data from database as dropdown. NB: it laravel 7

Comment: First `dd($suppliers)` then check value is exist. Pass your value in `products` blade.

Comment: problem @foreach($variable as $v) on the $variable